# How can override shipping API interface in Magento2

Tags: magento2, api, overrides, interface

I need to **override** below two core file of **vendor folder** :

**`vendor/magento/module-quote/Api/Data/ShippingMethodInterface.php`**

**`vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Cart/ShippingMethod.php`**

file to my code folder.

Answer (score 2):

`vendor/magento/module-quote/Api/Data/ShippingMethodInterface.php` is already **override magento quote model**.

> ```
> <preference for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface" 
> type="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethod" />
> ```

So you should Override the class `Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethod`

Not `ShippingMethodInterface`.

Comment: But how can I add my custom get, set method in ShippingMethodInterface and ShippingMethod?

Comment: @amitbera Is there any way to override the Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface to set value custom attribute on sales_order_place_after event?

Comment: i  need to check ..